# How to use ASP.NET Authorization Yet Permit Access to .css Files?

Tags: asp.net, css, web-config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I am using forms authentication, and when i place the arguments cited above, the css formatting I have done for the whole document is not being implemented, it's vanishing. what should i be doing so that the CSS remains intact.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I assume that your login form has an external CSS file, and that you're using Cassini or IIS 7 integrated mode.

Your `<deny users="?"/>` is preventing anonymous users from seeing the login form's CSS files.

You need to use the `<location>` element to allow anonymous users to see the CSS files, like this:

```
<location path="CSS">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue and this solution does not work for me.  I don't even have the deny users in my web config.

Comment: I figured it out.  It was something I missed from my checklist when setting up a new IIS application: Select the application, double-click "Authentication", select "Anonymous Authentication", then Edit, and change it to use the Application Pool Identity.  Make sure that user has permissions on the folder that contains the site.

Answer (score 6):

Use the location element to allow access to your css:

```
<configuration>
   <location path="style.css">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: <location path=”style.css”>
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users=”*”>
</allow>
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

I was trying this out, atlast your solution pointed out where I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<location path="Images">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

**

Answer (score -2):

please add this code in web config file

`<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" 
culture="en-GB"/>`

Comment: Answer is not relevant and no explaination is given to why this code should be added.