# ASP.Net login page problem

Tags: asp.net

I had a website project which worked fine. I have converted it into a web application project in VS 2010. Now when I start the project from VS my login page is never loaded because when it tries to load images, scripts, css all the requests are redirected back to login page.

However if I setup a website under my local IIS to use the folder where the project is the website works no problem.

I have created a test web app to play with. And it does pretty much the same. Login page cannot load an image because the request is redirected. 
Here is what I've got.

web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/login1.aspx" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx"  slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" requestLimit="150" mostRecent="false" />
  </system.web>
  <location path="trace.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

login1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login1.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestWebApp.login1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <img src="bcb.jpeg" />
login page
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestWebApp._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    default page  
    </div>  
    </form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

and the trace looks like

Requests to this Application Remaining: 140
No. Time of Request File Status Code Verb
1 11/30/2010 10:57:20 AM default.aspx 302 GET View Details
2 11/30/2010 10:57:20 AM login1.aspx 200 GET View Details
3 11/30/2010 10:57:22 AM bcb.jpeg 302 GET View Details
4 11/30/2010 10:57:22 AM login1.aspx 200 GET View Details

I'm missing something. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your `img` tag is malformed (`im g`). That might be it.

Comment: this web site did not allow me to put img tag as is

Answer (score 2):

See the following post for a solution:

[How to use ASP.NET Authorization Yet Permit Access to .css Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144274/how-to-use-asp-net-authorization-yet-permit-access-to-css-files)

Comment: Spot on - we use that technique to allow access to numerous resources prior to login.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid. I do not want to add locations in my web.config.